# How do I unit test an Angular HttpClient 204 response?

Tags: angular, httpclient, http-response-codes, no-data, http-status-code-204

Our REST service returns 204's for a no data scenario.  But I cannot figure out how to test for this scenario.

```
it('can handle no data', (done) => {
  const testData = service.getDummyData();
  service.dataChanged$.subscribe(
    (data: Data[]) => {
      expect(data).toBeUndefined();
      done();
    }
  );
  service.getData();
  const request: TestRequest = backend.expectOne(MyService.URL);
  request.flush(undefined, { status: 204, statusText: 'No Data' });
});
```

I've tried passing:

- undefined and false

  - `Error: Automatic conversion to JSON is not supported for response type.`
- null

  - response data is the string "null"

So, what should I be passing to the flush function to send an empty response?  I test the response in the service (simplified):

```
this.http.get<Data[]>(MyService.URL)
  .first().subscribe(
    (data: Data[]) => {
      if (data) {
        this.dataChanged$.next(data);
      } else {
        Logger.error(MyService.name, 'getData', 'No data.');
        this.dataChanged$.next(undefined);
      }
    },
    (error: Error) => {
        Logger.error(MyService.name, 'getData', error.message);
      this.dataChanged$.next(undefined);
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the simple answer is, pass '' to flush():

```
request.flush('', { status: 204, statusText: 'No Data' });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably fine to write

```
expect(data).toBeNull();
```

in fact you can very well write a variable with type `void` and value `null`. And then the request should be:

```
request.flush(null, { status: 204, statusText: 'No Data' });
```

Passing `""` to `flush` would also give `Error: Automatic conversion to JSON is not supported for response type.`